# Swift 3 Coredata makes error

Tags: swift, core-data

When I'm making a new project in Swift 3 using CoreData, I get this weird error.

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

I've been looking a lot after what this error means, but nothing works. I've tried to delete all the CoreData, and then the error goes away. But when I add it again, the error comes up.

Still haven't figured the issue. I've been into derived data and deleted the whole map, but nothing happens and the map comes again.

Comment: This occurs when we have 2 versions xcode installed. Close all of them, delete derive data and create your project again.

Comment: Create my project again? Ouch!

Comment: two version of xcode share the same derived data location. Thats what the problem is. You can try adding core data only and not creating from the scratch

Comment: In my case, I didn't created the whole project, I  just added core data model and its classes after quitting all xcode, simulators and cleaning derive data.

Comment: Tried to delete the xcdatamodel and add a new coredata file. It didn't work. So I made a new project, at copied all the codes. Then I added a entity, and the same error came up.

Comment: What about derived data ?

Comment: Not sure what it means

Comment: Google how to delete derive data of xcode

Comment: Ok cool. Which root should I delete? The whole project in the derived data?

Comment: Yea delete the complete contents in derive data folder. First force quit Xcode and simulator, then delete derive data and then start again with your project

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error and solved by the following.
Inspect the Entities, set the Module to "Current Product Module" and Codegen to "Manual/None".
ex:

[image]